# Add popups to geojson leaflet polylines

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I have the below code which generates polylines from a json file. I need each polyline to also have a unique popup. FYI tjhis code connects to a check box filter tool i put together.

I have seen similar questions however the answers dont work with my specific build.

```
window.onload=function(){

let checkboxStates

const jsontest = {"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [

<?php echo file_get_contents('data.json') ?>

]};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show does not build polylines.

It just defines a javascript variable.

To actually build the polylines, you need to use [L.geoJSON factory](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#geojson)

There is a very useful tutorial here: https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/example.html

Comment: I do actually have polyline generation working, just posted the wrong code. my bad. But the rest of the code i needed to get the popups working "blindpopup" was on the link you provided. works perfectly! thanks!